Expo provision file for tvOS
Expo is creating provision file for iOS even though I'm using Expo managed React Native TVOS.
/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/app.xcodeproj: error: Provisioning profile "*[expo] [app] [timestamp]" has platforms "visionOS, watchOS, and iOS", which does not match the current platform "tvOS". (in target 'app' from project 'app')

How can I force expo to create tvOS provision file?
I'd like to deploy tvOS app but there is not much of a documentation how to do it.
Please help
